# Merging multiple dataframes together with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have multiple dataframes that are structured as follows:

| Molecule Name | Molecular weight | Score | Population Score | Population Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 12 | 15 | 0.2 |
| B | 205 | 0.4 | 17 | 0.8 |
| C | 367 | 17 | 11 | 0.82 |
| D | 510 | 9 | 19.6 | 0.1 |

| Molecule Name | Molecular weight | Score | Population Score | Population Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 20 | 15 | 0.2 |
| B | 205 | 16 | 17 | 0.8 |
| E | 367 | 11 | 11 | 0.82 |
| F | 780 | 11 | 12 | 0.5 |

Imagine I had multiple dataframes where the molecule names, weights, and score can vary. But the population score and population error are the same across all dataframes.

I want to merge all the dataframes. The unique identifer is the Molecular weight. So if there are multiple dataframes which contain a molecular weight of 100, the scores of each get saved - take note of molecule C from the first dataframe and molecule E from the second - they have the same molecular weight so should be combined. I essentially want something that comes out like this:

| Molecule Name | Molecular weight | Score1 | Score2 | Population Score | Population Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 12 | 20 | 15 | 0.2 |
| B | 205 | 0.4 | 16 | 17 | 0.8 |
| C | 367 | 17 | 11 | 11 | 0.82 |
| D | 510 | 9 | 0 | 19.6 | 0.1 |
| F | 780 | 0 | 11 | 12 | 0.5 |

I have tried just simple merges but it always creates a new row for Molecule name E. I want to merge on Molecular weight. If the Molecular weight isn't in the original data frame then add a new row and populate the 0s. I hope this makes sense. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with de-duplication of the `Score` columns and [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html) to get the first molecule name:

```
dfs = [df1, df2] # could be more than 2 input DataFrames

out = (pd.concat([d.set_index(['Molecular weight', 'Population Score', 'Population Error'])
                   .rename(columns={'Score': f'Score{i}'})
                  for i, d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)], axis=1)
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Variant for future versions of pandas:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

out = (pd.concat([d.set_index(['Molecular weight', 'Population Score', 'Population Error'])
                   .rename(columns={'Score': f'Score{i}'})
                  for i, d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)], axis=1)
         .T.groupby(level=0).first().T
         .fillna(0)
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   Molecular weight  Population Score  Population Error Molecule Name  Score1  Score2
0               100              15.0              0.20             A    12.0      20
1               205              17.0              0.80             B     0.4      16
2               367              11.0              0.82             C    17.0      11
3               510              19.6              0.10             D     9.0       0
4               780              12.0              0.50             F     0.0      11
```

Comment: @BenWest first I recognized that it was a `concat`, then I thought that it would be great to have different names for `Score` and the same for `Molecule Name`, thus the `rename` and `groupby.first` ;)